# Change Language programmatically Like english to french wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, cultureinfo, culture

I found some tutorials and added two resources file to Properties folder of my project and named them "Resources.tr-TR.resx" and "Resources.en-US.resx" and as default my "Resources.resx" is file also there. I  set Access Modifier to "Public". And I call it in my xaml code like

`Content="{x:Static p:Resources.MainWindow}"`

In my files It has values and initially I can see it reads it correct. I have a menu button which changes the language and in action method I write

```
private void englishLanguageMenuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new   System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
}
```

or in another action lets say

```
private void macedonianLanguageMenuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR");
}
```

However system doesnt work. What is missing ? Can I dynamically change the language ? Or how can I change the resx file dynamically

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this

Add this code in your Application

```
/// <summary>
    /// Wraps up XAML access to instance of WPFLocalize.Properties.Resources, list of available cultures, and method to change culture
    /// </summary>
    public class CultureResources
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Backing filed for provider
        /// </summary>
        private static ObjectDataProvider provider;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets Resource provider
        /// </summary>
        public static ObjectDataProvider ResourceProvider
        {
            get
            {
                if (provider == null)
                {
                    provider = (ObjectDataProvider)App.Current.FindResource("Resources");
                }

                return provider;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Change the current culture used in the application.
        /// If the desired culture is available all localized elements are updated.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="culture">Culture to change to</param>
        public static void ChangeCulture(CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ////remain on the current culture if the desired culture cannot be found
            //// - otherwise it would revert to the default resources set, which may or may not be desired.

            V_Parcel.Properties.Resources.Culture = culture;
            ResourceProvider.Refresh();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Resources ObjectDataProvider uses this method to get an instance of the WPFLocalize.Properties.Resources class
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns resource instance</returns>
        public V_Parcel.Properties.Resources GetResourceInstance()
        {
            return new V_Parcel.Properties.Resources();
        }
    }
```

Add a XAML CultureDictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:resource="clr-namespace:Cultures">

    <!-- Resources ODP contains the current instance of the WPFLocalize.Properties.Resources class.
       Used in bindings to get localized strings and automatic updates when the culture is updated -->
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Resources" ObjectType="{x:Type resource:CultureResources}" MethodName="GetResourceInstance" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

In your App.XAml

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="CultureDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Binding should be like

```
Content="{Binding ShowTerminalName,Source={StaticResource Resources}}"
```

And in culture change event write this

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(currentCulture);
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(currentCulture);

                    CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(currentCulture);
                    CultureResources.ChangeCulture(cultureInfo);
```

> .resx Access modifier should be public

Comment: U write "ShowTerminalName" at resources right and named them like "Resource.en-US.resx" and "Resource.tr-TR.resx" ? I did it this way but it didnt work I mean at runtime it doesnt work

Comment: I have a resource named  ShowTerminalName at both the resources. it worked fine for me in runtime.

Comment: This even,ing I ll check again Now I have other stuff that I have to do :/

Comment: Thanks u Justine, very simplified explanation with all require steps.